# Typesafe substitution using parametrized reference

Tags: typesafe, hocon

Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
region : 2

regions {
    1 : us-east-1
    2 : eu-west-1
    3 : sa-east-1
}

# Desired outcome is `name : eu-west-1` (depending on the region value)
name : ${regions.${region}}
```

Comment: There's an open typesafe issue for this (nested substitution): https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/134